# How do I access component properties in a transcluded view in ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js, ember-components

I am passing some html to a components in ember. The html is yielded.
But the yielded html is unable to access properties defined in the component. However the properties do work on the component template.

*component*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  user: undefined,
  replyText: undefined,

  onInitialization: function(){
    this.set('replyText', '@' + this.user.get('username') + ' ');
  }.on("init"),

  remainingTweetChars: function () {
    var length = 140 - this.get('replyText').length;

    return length;
  }.property('replyText')

});
```

*component template*

```
{{remainingTweetChars}} {{!-- this works --}}

{{yield}}
```

*component usage with html which is yielded into the component template above*

```
{{#action-reply class="item-actionables__reply"
  user=user
}}

  <span>{{remainingTweetChars}}</span> {{!-- this does NOT works --}}
  <span>{{view.remainingTweetChars}}</span> {{!-- this does NOT works --}}
{{/action-reply}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To overcome this you can assign a `viewName` to the component and use it to reference any property defined.

Example,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bihuzupogi/1/edit?html,js,output

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
    <h3>Component in block form example accessing props</h3>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">

  {{#test-comp propInTmpl="test-prop-in-tmpl" viewName="the-test-comp"}}
  <span style="color:gray">
  this is content of the block content <b>without</b> using <b>viewName</b>
   (<b>props:</b> {{propInTmpl}}, {{propInClass}})
  </span>
  <br/>
  <span style="color:gray">
  this is content of the block content using the <b>viewName</b>
   (<b>props:</b> {{view.the-test-comp.propInTmpl}}, {{view.the-test-comp.propInClass}})
  </span>
  {{/test-comp}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/test-comp">

  <i>This is content of test-compo component template! (<b>props:</b> {{propInTmpl}}, {{propInClass}})</i>
  <br/>
  {{yield}}
  </script>
```

**js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.TestCompComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  propInClass:"test-prop-in-class"
});
```

Comment: Thanks @melc given that ember 2.0 (guess they are doing it in next version 1.10) is deprecating `views` for `components`.
I wonder if the keyword `view` would be maintained. Is there any other way?

Comment: @ahmed can you please provide the resource that states that? i haven't noticed it. This solution is based on the fact that a containing view or component will be able to access itselft via the viewName property available to its parent view. So as long as it is possible to access the parent view this will work. I think that there will always be a way to access the parent view so there will be no problem.

Comment: @ahmed in ember 2.0 you will be able to yield values from inside the component. see: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gefahulavi/1/edit